Can't upload files to firebase cloud storage. Error: "No objects exists with the desired reference"
All requests using the firebase cloud storage sdk result in a "no objects exists with the desired reference". The same code built with expo and react native runs perfectly well on a friend's machine.Other firebase services seem to work, such as firestore and firebase cloud messaging.
This is the hook used to invoke the firebase uploadfile request:
import { useState } from "react";
import { UseMutateFunction, useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ImagePickerAsset } from "expo-image-picker";
import storage from "@/storage/init";

type uploadFileResult = {
  uploadFile: UseMutateFunction<
    string | undefined,
    Error,
    uploadFileArgs,
    unknown
  >;
  uploadProgress: number;
  isUploading: boolean;
  error: Error | null;
  downloadURL: string | null;
};
type uploadFileArgs = { file: ImagePickerAsset };

//Handles file upload to Firebase storage.
export function useUploadFile(): uploadFileResult {
  const [uploadProgress, setUploadProgress] = useState(0);
  const [downloadURL, setDownloadURL] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const uploadFile = async (props: uploadFileArgs) => {
    const localFilePath = props.file.uri;
    console.info(localFilePath);
    if (!localFilePath) return;

    const reference = storage.ref(`${props.file.fileName}`);
    const task = reference.putFile(localFilePath);

    task.on("state_changed", (taskSnapshot) => {
      setUploadProgress(
        (taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes) * 100,
      );
    });

    await task;

    const url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
    setDownloadURL(url);
    return url;
  };

  const {
    mutate,
    isPending: isUploading,
    error,
  } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: uploadFile,
  });

  return {
    uploadFile: mutate,
    uploadProgress,
    isUploading,
    error,
    downloadURL,
  };
}

This is the implementation of said hook:
import { SettingsToolbar } from "@/components/screens/settings/Toolbar";
import { Avatar } from "@/components/ui/Avatar";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/Button";
import { Input, InputBox, InputLabel } from "@/components/ui/Input";
import { Tags } from "@/components/ui/Tags";
import { ToastType } from "@/components/ui/Toast";
import { UserRepo } from "@/db/user";
import { useTheme } from "@/hooks/useTheme";
import { trimAll } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Gender } from "@/models/models";
import { useShowToast } from "@/providers/toastProvider";
import { useUserContext } from "@/providers/userProvider";
import { Timestamp } from "@react-native-firebase/firestore";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import { router } from "expo-router";
import { Pencil } from "lucide-react-native";
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import {
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Pressable,
  ScrollView,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { GenderSelect, InterestedInSelect } from "./signup";
import { useUploadFile } from "@/hooks/useFileUpload";

export default function Settings() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const user = useUserContext();
  const showToast = useShowToast();
  const { uploadFile, downloadURL } = useUploadFile();

  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(user?.avatar || "");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(user?.username || "");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState<Gender>(user?.gender || "male");
  const [lookingFor, setLookingFor] = useState(user?.lookingFor[0] || "female");
  const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>(
    user?.tags.filter((v) => v !== user.gender) || [],
  );

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setAvatar(result.assets[0].uri);
      uploadFile({ file: result.assets[0] });
      return;
    }
    showToast("Image upload was cancelled", ToastType.WARNING);
  };

  const updateUser = useCallback(() => {
    try {
      if (username.length < 3) {
        throw Error("Username is too short!");
      }

      if (trimAll(username) !== username) {
        throw Error("Username has incorrect format!");
      }
      if (username.length > 20) {
        throw Error("Username is too long!");
      }

      if (user) {
        const userRepo = new UserRepo(user.id);
        //user.avatar = avatar;
        user.username = username;
        user.gender = gender;
        user.tags = [gender, ...tags];
        user.lookingFor = [lookingFor, ...tags];
        user.lastOnline = Timestamp.now();
        if (downloadURL) {
          user.avatar = downloadURL;
        }
        userRepo
          .updateUser(user)
          .then(() => {
            router.back();
            showToast("Settings updated", ToastType.INFO);
          })
          .catch((r) => {
            console.error(r);
            showToast("Error updating settings", ToastType.ERROR);
          });
      }
    } catch (r) {
      {
        console.warn(r);
        showToast(`${r}`, ToastType.WARNING);
      }
    }
  }, [downloadURL, gender, lookingFor, showToast, tags, user, username]);

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: theme.background }}
    >
      <SettingsToolbar />
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            paddingHorizontal: 42,
            marginTop: 40,
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Pressable onPress={pickImage}>
            <Avatar size={128} src={avatar} />
            <Pencil
              style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, end: 0 }}
              color={theme.onSecondary}
            />
          </Pressable>
        </View>
        <View style={{ alignItems: "center", gap: 8, marginBottom: 40 }}>
          <Input>
            <InputLabel style={{ color: theme.text }}>Username</InputLabel>
            <InputBox
              maxLength={20}
              value={username}
              onChangeText={setUsername}
            />
          </Input>
          <GenderSelect gender={gender} onChange={setGender} />
          <InterestedInSelect gender={lookingFor} onChange={setLookingFor} />
          <Tags tags={tags} setTags={setTags} />
          <Button onPress={updateUser}>Save</Button>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

Again, this issue only seems to persist on my machine with my emulator/phone. After some debugging I also found out that I'm unable to even list the items in the default bucket. I get the same error. That leads me to believe that maybe the reference that "doesn't" exist is the default reference of the bucket itself? Any ideas on what could be a possible problem ?
Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Okay, for some reason firebase was not able to find the default bucket. So every time that I tried to put a file into the storage (which I had initiated as storage()) It resulted in a "No object reference exists..." Which just meant that the bucket could not be found... So what I did to fix it is to initialize the storage as if it is a custom bucket:
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/storage";
const storage = firebase.app().storage(process.env.BUCKET_URL);
export default storage;

Still I have no idea why it can't find the default bucket...

Glad that you got this fixed. Can you please check your firebase config to see what Bucket URL is there? And how does it compare to the one you're getting from process.env ? The default bucket has recently changed from <project_id>.appspot.com to <project_id>.firebasestorage.app, so it might be that you just have an old config.

Before I actually didn't specify any bucket url. (just called storage()) As far as I know this is supposed to point towards the default bucket, right ? But for some reason firebase couldn't find a reference to that...
